# Implementation defined to use a reserved vector without resizing it?

Tags: c++, vector

Is it implementation defined to use a reserved vector without resizing it?

By that I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> foo;
    foo.reserve(1024);
    foo[0] = 10;

    std::cout<<foo[0];
    return 0;
}
```

In the above, I reserve a good amount of space and I assigned a value to one of the indices in that space. However, I did not call push_back which "resizes" the vector and gives it a default value for each element (which I'm trying to avoid). So in this `foo.size()` is 0 while `foo.capacity()` is 1024.

So is this valid code or is it implementation defined? Seeing as I'm assigning to a vector with "0" size. It works but I'm not sure if it's a good idea..

The reason I'm trying to avoid the default value is because for large allocations, I don't need it "zero-ing" out each index as I will decide when I want to write to it or not. I'd use a raw pointer but the `lodepng` API accepts only a vector for decoding from file.

Comment: *"is this valid code or is it implementation defined?"*  It is neither valid, nor defined.

Comment: if you `reserve` and then `push_back` it won't need to resize until you hit (at least) the reserved size

Comment: Your code introduces undefined behavior, no different than accessing an array element with an out-of-bounds index.

Comment: But I don't understand why the index is out of bounds if `reserve` allocated memory for it..

Comment: @Brandon Your program immediately asserts when accessing element 0 when run in debug mode for Visual C++.  The assertion is "vector subscript out of range".  I hope that is convincing enough to not do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Brandon it's because `std::vector` guarantees that its elements are validly constructed.  If you don't want that, `std::vector` is the wrong container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) just *reserves* memory, so the next `push_back` does not have to allocate memory. It does not change the size of the vector.

If you want a vector with an initial *size* of `1024` elements, you can use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) to do that:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> foo(1024);
```

Note that if you create a vector with an initial size of e.g. `1024` elements, if you then do `push_back` you *add* an element, so the size of the vector increases to `1025` elements.

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal, regardless of the type of item in the container or what seems to happen on a particular compiler. From 23.1.1/12 (Table 68) we learn that `operator[]` behaves like `*(a.begin() + n)`. Since you haven't added any items to the container this is the same as accessing an iterator past `end()` which is undefined.